# How to add pywin32 tray icon menu separator / divider?

Tags: python, contextmenu, pywin32, trayicon

Based on this pywin32 based [script](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) how can I add a separator/divider to the tray menu `menu_options` ?

Can I also make the menu pop on left click and not just right click ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the *notify* function (starting at line *#135* in your *URL*) from:

```py
def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
    elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
        self.show_menu()
    elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
        pass
    return True
```

to:

```py
def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    if lparam == win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
    elif lparam in (win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP):
        self.show_menu()
    return True
```

Explanation:

- ***notify*** is a *callback* function that gets executed automatically when a message is sent to the tray control, and instead of doing nothing when receiving a *WM_LBUTTONUP* (mouse left button released) message, we simply show the menu as when receiving *WM_RBUTTONUP* (mouse right button released)